# What is difference between InternalArray and Array in Google V8?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, v8

In Google javascript engine v8, there are InternalArray and Array. Array is exposed to users while InternalArray is only for internal use. What is the exact difference between these two? Or in fact InternalArray is the same as Array?

Comment: I mean the code like var arr = new InternalArray() in v8 source.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the `InternalArray` is used only internally and is not exposed to JavaScript directly.

Since you can easily change the behavior of all Arrays by adding properties to `Array.prototoype`. This means that there are no fixed guarantees that any Array function will have behave in a certain way. V8 implements part of the [JavaScript Specification](http://tc39.github.io/ecma262) in JavaScript itself (see the src/js directory).

```
Array.prototype[0] = 'property';
Array.prototype.length = 20;
// Now every Array has a value at 0 and a length of 20:
console.log([][0]);
console.log([].length);
```

It is important that the functionality always conforms to the specification and isn't accidentally changed by the user. This would for instance be the case with the normal `Array`. Hence, whenever V8 requires fixed array-like functionality, the `InternalArray` is used. It has it's own, detached prototype that is not exposed to the user.

Comment: Thanks very much. Eh, did you mean that InternalArray is somehow a "FIXED"-length array?

Comment: No not fixed-length, but as I said fixed behavior (see the example above how changes to Array.prototype can alter default behavior).

Comment: "Since you can easily change the behavior of all Arrays by adding properties to Array.prototoype."  You can also easily be summarily executed for doing so.

Comment: Yeah, I think we all agree that monkeypatching isn't ideal :), but that doesn't prevent it from happening.